# Error en consulta MySQL de varias tablas

Tags: mysql

Buenas tardes vengo a ustedes gran comunidad de programadores para que me puedan ayudar con esta consulta que la verdad llevo varios dias y no he podido pasar de ahi.

Tengo la siguiente consulta donde muestro en una tabla datos de unos pacientes y sus estudios el cual las tengo en 2 consultas aparte donde una solo los datos del paciente y otra consulta donde pido los estudios del paciente.

Mi problema es que quiero hacer estas 2 consultas en una sola

Hasta ahora tengo esto y el problema que solo me devuelve una sola linea y es la misma siempre.

```
SELECT
  d.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.nombre_producto SEPARATOR ' | '),
  f.*,
  c.*,
  u.*,
  p.*,
  m.*
FROM facturas f,
     clientes c,
     users u,
     medicos m,
     detalle_factura d,
     productos p
WHERE f.id_cliente = c.id_cliente 
  AND f.id_vendedor = u.user_id 
  AND f.id_medico = m.id_medico 
  AND d.id_producto = p.id_producto 
  AND d.numero_factura = f.numero_factura;
```

**Como quiero que se vea:**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se me muestra al checarlo en phpmyadmin y en el sistema:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estas son las tablas a las que llamo la info:

Tabla facturas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla usuarios:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla productos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla detalle factura:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla medicos:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Clientes:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No necesitas las mayúsculas sostenidas para gritarnos tu pregunta. Por favor, evítalas.

Comment: @Alfabravo listo ya lo corregí como debe de ser y disculpa, es que con tanto rollo que tengo en mi mente no me fije y expuse todo al trancazo.

Comment: Pregunta: la segunda parte es una pregunta diferente? La primera parte se resolvió con la respuesta aceptada? Si es así, para que la respuesta aceptada siga siéndolo, por favor pon la segunda parte en una nueva pregunta.

Comment: @Alfabravo si es otra pregunta aparte, y si ahorita lo compongo y hago otra pregunta. sobre la duda no sabes cual pueda ser el error?.

Comment: EN la nueva pregunta te respondo con todo gusto

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prueba así y me comentas si notas algún avance:

```
SELECT
  d.*,
  GROUP_CONCAT(p.nombre_producto SEPARATOR ' | '),
  f.*,
  c.*,
  u.*,
  p.*,
  m.*
  FROM facturas f 
  JOIN clientes c
  JOIN users u
  JOIN medicos m
  JOIN detalle_factura d
  JOIN productos p
  ON  f.id_cliente = c.id_cliente 
  AND f.id_vendedor = u.user_id 
  AND f.id_medico = m.id_medico 
  AND d.id_producto = p.id_producto 
  AND d.numero_factura = f.numero_factura
  GROUP BY id_cliente,numero_factura;
```

Simplemente he sustituido los productos cartesianos por `JOIN` y he utilizado un `GROUP_BY` para agrupar por paciente y fecha. Espero que sea lo que esperabas.

Es normal que vieras una única línea porque estabas utilizando la función de totales `GROUP_CONCAT` sin un `GROUP_BY`.

Déjame cualquier duda en los comentarios.

Comment: muchas gracias mi hermano la verdad me haz ayudado y si era lo que buscaba, gracias de verdad.